# Opening ads within UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hyperlink, admob, iad

Is it possible to open ads from either Admob or iAd ads in a UIWebview within the same app rather than in safari?? cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is an advertiser setting, and unfortunately can't be controlled by the app developer.